# Android + GoogleAnalytics: Screen Name changes without (apparent) reason

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm having problems tracking my app with Google Analytics.
In all the activities that I need to track (2 for now, more in the future) I have the same code for GA handling:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
    easyTracker.activityStop(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
    easyTracker.activityStart(this);
    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    if (uncaughtExceptionHandler instanceof ExceptionReporter) {
      ExceptionReporter exceptionReporter = (ExceptionReporter) uncaughtExceptionHandler;
      exceptionReporter.setExceptionParser(new AnalyticsExceptionParser());
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    Tracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
    easyTracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, SCREEN_LABEL);
    easyTracker.send(
            MapBuilder
            .createAppView()
            .build());

    super.onResume();
}
```

And here's the analytics.xml file:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

    <!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXX-Y</string>

    <!-- Enable automatic activity tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">10</integer>

</resources>
```

The problem is that at the first visualization of the activity the screen name results to be correct (`Home Screen` for one activity and `Login Screen` for the other). But at the second visualization the screen name changes to the `Qualified Name` of the activity (`it.prova.HomePage` for one activity and `it.prova.LoginPanel` for the other one).

Where am I wrong?

THX

P.S. obviously, where I write UA-XXXXXXX-Y I have the correct string, not this example one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem: I had to change this

```
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
```

into this

```
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">false</bool>
```

So now i have complete control of the tracking in my code.